# Checksum for Github Repository

Tags: repository, checksum

How can I compute a checksum of the contents of a Github repository such that two repos with different histories but identical contents yield the same checksum?

I attempted computing checksums with the repositories' tarballs, but ran into trouble due to differing timestamps between files which are otherwise identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for anyone else who might need one.

It creates a hash from the hashes of objects in the tree of the latest commit.

```js
console = { log: log };

// construct hash of a github repository

function getRepoHash(login, repo, cb) {
    
  // get latest commit
  ghapi('getRepoCommits', login, repo, { per_page: 1 }, function (err, res, commits) {
      
      // get tree of last commit
      ghapi('getRepoGitTree', login, repo, commits[0].sha, function (err, res, body) {
          
          // construct an array of shas from tree
          var shas = body.tree.map(function (obj) {
            return obj.sha;
          });
          
          // hash the shas
          var repoSha = sha1(shas.toString()).toString();
          cb(null, repoSha);
      })
  })
}

// nodejs/io.js vs joyent/node

getRepoHash('nodejs', 'io.js', function (err, sha1) {
  getRepoHash('joyent', 'node', function (err, sha2) {
    var equal = sha1 === sha2;
    console.log('nodejs/io.js '+ sha1)
    console.log('joyent/node '+ sha2)
    console.log('equal? '+ equal)
  });
});

// logging
function log(message) {
      var logger = document.getElementById('log');
      logger.innerHTML += message + '<br>';
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sha1/0.3.0/sha1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/ghapi@latest"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```